# How do housing developments affect the soil of the surroundings? Are the minerals/molecules in cement available to plants? Or is the soil too basic?

Tags: soil, minerals, plant

Calcium carbonate in cement can make the soil more alkaline but does that make large housing developments have a significant or negligible affect on availability of nutrients? Does it cause nutrients to be more available to plants or does it end up leaching them away?